# ng-bootstrap 1.0 - Progressbar centering value

Tags: bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

We are using ng-bootstrap's progressbar and want to center the value text in the overall bar rather than center it in the green progress area.

EDIT: An image of what I mean, need the value where the red box is.
[image]

**What I have so far is the following, which is not working:**

```
.progress-text {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

<ngb-progressbar type="success" showValue="false" [value]="data?.progress" [striped]="false" [animated]="false">
    <span class="progress-text">{{data?.progress}}%</span>
</ngb-progressbar>
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the custom css you'll need in this case (I initially misunderstood your requirements):

```html
.progress-text {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 49%; /* just in case calc is unavailable in a browser */
    left: calc(50% - 12px);
}
```

And here's a working example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.progress-text {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 49%; /* just in case calc is unavailable in a browser */
    left: calc(50% - 12px);
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="progress mt-5">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <span class="progress-text">25%</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```